# Forward and centered finite difference give same error plot: why?

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences, error-propagation, truncation-error

Let us consider the following standard approximations of the first derivative of a function

$$FD = \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

$$CFD = \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$$

The first is *first order accurate*, while the second it *second order accurate*.

Consider now $f=\sin(x)$ and $x =2\pi$. If we plot in loglog scale the error as a function of the stepsize $h$, we obtain the following graph, where it appears that the accuracy is the same.

[image: error plot]

---

*My attempt to explain it*

I look at the truncation error for the forward derivative:

$$\tau_1 = f''(x) \frac{h}{2} + f^{(3)}(x) \frac{h^2}{6} + O(h^3)$$

Looking at the plot, I would expect that the first term of the truncation error is $0$. So, I note that $f''(x)=-\sin(x)$, and for $x \approx 2\pi$ it is almost $0$. Therefore the leading error term is $-\cos(x) \frac{h^2}{2}$, which should motivate the second order accuracy.

**Is it correct** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular case is simply because the approximations themselves are (modulo floating point error) exactly the same for the same value of $h$:

$$\frac{\sin(2\pi+h)-\sin(2\pi)}{h}=\frac{\sin(2\pi+h)}{h}$$

whereas

$$\frac{\sin(2\pi+h)-\sin(2\pi-h)}{2h}=\frac{2\sin(2\pi+h)}{2h}=\frac{\sin(2\pi+h)}{h}$$

because of the fact that $\sin$ is an odd function when reflected through $2\pi$. Numerically this won't be *exactly* true but it will be close enough that they'll be indistinguishable except maybe for extremely small $h$.

Comment: Thanks @Ian. Is my procedure also acceptable, from your point of view?

Comment: @andereBen I would say that noting that the second derivative vanishes at the point of expansion wouldn't explain why the similarity is quite as pronounced as it is by itself.

Comment: Thanks, now it's clearer

Answer (score 0):

Finite differences suffer from two sources of errors:

- truncation error (given by the Taylor series). It decreases with $h$.
- evaluation error due to floating-point arithmetic. It goes to infinity when $h$ goes to 0.

That's the reason finite differences go nuts when $h$ goes to 0 (here around $10^{-5}$). For centered finite differences, we should definitely expect the same behavior, but different slopes.

Edit 2: for $\sin$, indeed the Taylor series indicates that the truncation error is already a $O(h^2)$.

Comment: The question is not about why the approximation is bad for $h$ too small. The question is about why the two approximation coincides. Btw, the code works for other cases, and I'm sure it's right. @cvanaret

Comment: I edited my message at the same time you posted. It doesn't hurt to have a bigger picture of the graph ;) Simply test with another function to check.

Comment: it works with $\exp(x)$, and also with $\cos(x)$ (evaluated at $x=1$), the OP has to be a special case.

Btw, you wrote "For centered finite differences, we should definitely expect the same behavior, but different slopes". In the plot there are *both* centered and forward finite differences error w.r.t. the true derivative $\cos(2 \pi)$.

Comment: Also, why $O(h^3)$? I would say that the truncation error is $O(h^2)$... because it's the first that does not vanish at $x=2 \pi$

Comment: Oh my bad, I was thinking of $x = 0$.
I meant that FD and CD have different slopes in the general case. Of course if terms vanish, you may get the same behavior, like in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I think the two forms turn out to be identical for $f = \sin$ and $x = 2\pi$, because $\sin(2\pi) = 0$ and $\sin(2\pi + h) = - \sin(2\pi - h)$.